# Can we make Visualforce Page of a managed package publically accessible

Tags: apex, managed-package

Can we make a Visualforce Page of a managed package publicly accessible in Salesforce sites? If yes, then how we can achieve that?

Comment: would you not just access them in the normal way prefixing the page with the namespace? e.g. ns__YourPage ?

Comment: Yes, create a Site, that is Force.com site and use that Visualforce page as the source for that site. Make that site publically available.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create a Site, that is Force.com site and use that Visualforce page as the source for that site. Make that site publically available. 
Go to setup - Sites -> Register your domain. Once your unique domain is registered. Create a new site and give your desired visualforce as the source for site.